# Java Error: Could not find or load main class G when Running Hadoop NameNode -format

Tags: java, hadoop

I'm encountering an error while trying to format the Hadoop NameNode using the command hadoop namenode -format. Whenever I execute this command, I receive the following error message:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class G
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: G
```

Here are the details about my environment:

Operating System: Windows 11
Java Version: jdk-21
Hadoop Version: hadoop-3.3.6
Hadoop Installation Path: C:\hadoop-3.3.6
Java Home Path: C:\Java\jdk-21
I've confirmed that both Java and Hadoop are installed correctly, and the environment variables JAVA_HOME and HADOOP_HOME are properly set. However, despite these checks, I'm still encountering the error.

Could anyone provide insights into why this error might be occurring and how to resolve it? Additionally, if there are any specific configurations or steps needed to run Hadoop on Windows 11 with Java jdk-21, please let me know.

Comment: I assume your windows username has been space before your last name `Gajul`? If so, Hadoop won't work with that. It's recommended to run Hadoop on Linux, not windows

Comment: Yes my username contains spaces but are you sure i should install it on ubuntu?

Comment: Most hadoop official documentation assumes you're using Linux. It doesn't have to be Ubuntu. Otherwise, you'll have to change your windows username